# Remove certain text before pasting it

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, clipboard, copy-paste

I have a paste event where i get certain plain text, so i want to remove a text from the copied text and paste it.

text copied in `Clipboard`

```
<p style="font:10pt Times New Roman, Times;" pid="123">
    This Amendment contains only the Cover Page, this Explanatory Note.
</p>
```

So i want to remove is `pid="123"` , how can i possibly be able to do it?

```
    myTextArea.addEventListener('paste', (e) => {
     let html = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
                
     console.log('i pasted', html);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex pattern and `replace` method to get the correct string. Here is the code:

```
myTextArea.addEventListener('paste', (e) => {
 let html = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
 let transformed_html = html.replace(/pid=\"[0-9]*\"/, "");
 console.log('i pasted', transformed_html);
 
 const selection = window.getSelection();
 if (!selection.rangeCount) return false;
 selection.deleteFromDocument();
 selection.getRangeAt(0).insertNode(document.createTextNode(transformed_html));

 event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: i have little knowledge of regex so if i have random text & number so what should i put?
`pid=a18cbae3f9e3cb7e3f6eca8a03937d64`
`/pid=\w\"[0-9]*\"/` ?

Comment: if the `pid` is only going to be alpha-numeric then you can put: `/pid=\"[0-9|a-z|A-Z]*\"/`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an element first in order to change attributes.

otherwise you'll have to do string manipulation, either using loops or Regex.

```js
let htmlAsText = `<p style="font:10pt Times New Roman, Times" pid="123">
    This Amendment contains only the Cover Page, this Explanatory Note.
</p>`;

let div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = htmlAsText;
div.querySelector("p").removeAttribute("pid");

document.querySelector("body").appendChild(div)
```

[createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
[removeAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)

Comment: Actually i understood that in sourceEditing mode when i have `html` its in plain text so i want to remove that `pid` everytime i copy and paste it.
my bad i just changed the information that i want to remove the text not as in attribute.

Comment: @SDP I have updated my answer, hope that helps